Flask api giving different results from model
The problem am facing is that my flask api is giving different result and confidence score from my model itself, when i give image to model it give the below result
Model result
Flask result on same image
I have tried improving image quality and applied filters but that increase the confidence score of my affected images also,
below is my flask code
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image, ImageEnhance, ImageFilter

app = Flask(__name__)

Load the pre-trained model
model = tf.keras.models.load_model('binary_eye_model.h5')

def preprocess_image(image):
    if image.mode != 'RGB':
        image = image.convert('RGB')

    image = image.filter(ImageFilter.SHARPEN)
    enhancer = ImageEnhance.Contrast(image)
    image = enhancer.enhance(0.5)

    original_size = image.size
    target_size = (64, 64)

    if original_size != target_size:
        image.thumbnail(target_size, Image.LANCZOS)
        new_image = Image.new("RGB", target_size, (255, 255, 255))
        new_image.paste(
            image,
            ((target_size[0] - image.size[0]) // 2, (target_size[1] - image.size[1]) // 2)
        )
        image = new_image

    img_array = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(image)
    img_array = np.expand_dims(img_array, axis=0) / 255.0

    return img_array


@app.route('/detect', methods=['POST'])
def predict():
    file = request.files.get('file')

    if not file or file.filename == '':
        return jsonify({'error': 'No valid file provided'}), 400

    try:
        image = Image.open(file.stream)

        processed_image = preprocess_image(image)

        prediction = model.predict(processed_image)

        confidence_score = prediction[0][0]
        eye = 'Normal' if confidence_score >= 0.9 else 'Affected'

        return jsonify({'predicted_eye': eye, 'confidence_score': float(confidence_score)})
    except Exception as e:
        return jsonify({'error': 'Error processing the image: ' + str(e)}), 500


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)

I tried image filters but they also increase the confidence score of the images that belong to my other class, i have applied contrast and image filters
